# Can I insert references to individual slides into a PowerPoint deck that would be updated automatically?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, cross-reference

Suppose I am creating a large deck and want to insert a slide at the beginning that would essentially be a table of contents. Something like:

- Introduction: slides 1-10
- Section on Foo: slides 11-15
- Section on Bar: slides 16-22

etc. Is there a way to make those slide number references updateable automatically as I change my deck and add or remove slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the way you probably expect, but with the same effect.

Separate the slides into three different files, then create a new file that's effectively your table of contents.

Add shapes or text to the table of contents (TOC) presentation's sole slide and link each to the sub-presentations. Before doing this, save the TOC presentation once and make sure it and the sub-presentations are in the same folder.

Now when you have the TOC presentation open and click one of the links, the linked presentation will open (in front of the TOC presentation).  When you quit the linked presentation or move past the last slide and it quits automatically, you'll be back at the TOC slide, ready to move to the next sub-presentation.